# ROS node connection is not active

Tags: ros-kinetic, python2.7

I'm using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 with a real robot. I'm loading a map on topic /map with the map_server node and I'm trying to subscribe the /map topic with a personal node called my_node, however I'm not able to get the map data on my node. It is really strange because if I use RViz I can see the map subscribing the /map topic. If I run roswtf it says that map_server and my_node are not connected (/map) and if I run rqt_graph I can see that the link between map_server --> /map --> my_node exist but it is not active. Furthermore I noted that rostopic echo works for me only with specifics topics but not with all of them (for example rostopic echo /tf works but rostopic echo /map doesn't work). Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Rosnode list:
[image: rosnode list]

Rostopic list:
[image: rostopic list]

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of `rosnode list` and `rostopic list`. You should copy/paste the text and format it as code (rather than using a screenshot.) Also tell us if you are using gazebo or this is for a real robot.

Comment: I'm using a real robot, you can see the rosnode list and rostopic list in the edit session.

Comment: There is no "edit session" (whatever that is) that is visible in your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, now you can see the edit session

Answer (score 0):

you are running just one ROS Network, right? As you are working with a real robot, I don't know if you are using another computer to work in the network that is running on the real robot. If that's your case, make sure you the parameters needed to work with [Multiple Machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) in one single network.

I say this because in your rostopic list there's no /tf topic and that's why you cannot do rostopic echo to that topic.

Also try to use rosnode info and rostopic info to see which subscriptions and publishers are being created and see if your node is working as it should.

Edit 1:
My apologies for the misunderstanding. Perhaps it is due to latched topics ([see here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers)).
Latched topics are a special topic that only publishes the last message that was published on it. It is normally used in static data such as a map.

That being said, I would encourage you to try to retrieve the map using the service that map_server offers, which sends you the information of the map as an OccupancyGrid data. Is this enough for the purpose?

Comment: I'm not using multiple machines, I'm just running one ROS network, that of the robot. I have /tf topic, just it is not in the picture. Using rosnode info and rostopic info everythink seems good, indeed when I run rqt_graph I can see the connection between map_server and my_node on the topic /map but this connection is not active, I can see the connection with nodes/topics all but not with nodes/topics active

Comment: Please check my edited answer for more details.

Comment: When I try to run rosservice call /static_map I get the following error: DeserializationError cannot deserialize: unknown error handler name 'rosmsg'

Comment: Check your genpy version. It seems there was a bug in Kinetic distribution and it was fixed in version 0.6.13 (please see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/360537/unknown-error-handler-name-rosmsg/) for more details). I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually I have genpy 0.6.14, I tried to do pip install genpy==0.6.13 or pip install genpy==0.6.15 but they don't work, resource not found. Maybe, if it exist, I should use an alternative mode to install a new genpy version (not via pip).

Comment: How did you create the map? Could you load the one from turtlebot3_tutorials or similar and see if you can use the service to retrieve it? We need to see if the issue is related to the map or any package that is not working properly.

Comment: I created the map with gmapping and I saved it with map_saver. Actually I have not the robot with me so I can't try to load the map from turtlebot3_tutorial, anyway I really think that the problem is with some package that is not working properly, for example genpy (also because I can correctly see my map in RViz).